# Building find my phone website with Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have an idea of building a travel/security mobile app connected with website, and besides other functionalities i should be able to find my phone on a map... similar to apple's iCloud web. Is that possible in Reactjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. that is possible. There are many packages which gives the exact location of user.ex:- `react-geolocated`. Every time when the users location is updated make an api call to save in the db. and show the similar changes in other side (who is tracking the location).

Comment: Thank you! So i would basically fetch the location from mobile location db to website..